# How to call a stored proc from LINQ to SQL if working "code-first"

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I need to call a stored proc from LINQ to SQL. I know that in a database-first approach, you simply drag the stored proc into your LINQ to SQL designer, and the stored proc code will be generated for you.

However, I'm using LINQ to SQL in a code-first approach, where I create my domain classes, and add attributes to hook them up to LINQ to SQL. I'm not sure how to call my stored procs this way.

Comment: If you're creating classes that will eventually be LINQ to SQL entities, why don't you create them using Entity Designer in Visual Studio?  You can create regular classes there even if they have no database mapping (yet).  Manually adding/managing all those attributes sounds like a nightmare - and the designer makes it a breeze.  The designer will create partial classes and properties for you, so you'll have to put your customizations  (methods, etc) in another partial class file (which is the usual way LINQ to SQL entity classes are handled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to do a database-first approach to auto generate the cs code for that, and then implement that code in your (manual) code.

If you implement MySPResult that way, you can use it:

```
ISingleResult<MySPResult> spResult = DataContext.MySP( params )
```

Do you need to use LINQ to SQL for this? You can call SP on a DbCommand. If you need to return your POCO entity, you can still convert it manually or write a general entity converter.

(Also consider if you need to use SP at all; you can use standard LINQ, LINQ as expression, dynamic query, then you don't have to implement the otherwise auto-generated typed wrapper code.)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I looked at the database-first generated code and the code it generates is very tightly bound to its own DataContext subclass. Not looking like an easy thing to pull out, I decided to have a DBML file that I just use for stored procs, which works well.